# Invalid response in Implementing multiColumn SearchView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, searchview, android-search

I am making a project in which I display the contents of database in a multicolumn list view. Now, I further want to add the search functionality. Search seems to be working fine, but it displays the row twice. I have no idea what is causing this. I think that It displays once from name and once from ticketID. How can I make it filter the results based only on the first column i.e Name and not any other..Please help...Im awfully stuck on this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnRefreshListener,OnQueryTextListener{
 GetDataFromDB getdb = new GetDataFromDB();
String data = "";
int flag=0;
String data2="";
SearchView mSearchView;
SimpleAdapter adapter_title,adapter;
HashMap<String, String>  map2;
ListView list,list_head;
//ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> users;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist_title;
TextView label;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    list_head = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); 
    mylist_title = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
   // tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);


    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();
    users = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",8000).show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this,"NO INTERNET CONNECTION DETECTED",8000).show();
        Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!");    
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            data = getdb.GetDataFromDB();

            System.out.println(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    System.out.println(users);
                   users = parseJSON(data);
                   System.out.println(users);
                   addHeader();
                   addData();

                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}







@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>parseJSON(String result) {

    try {

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        System.out.println("Printing Jarray length--");
        System.out.println(jArray.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            System.out.println(users);          
            System.out.println(json_data.getString("Name"));

          map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map2.put("Name", json_data.getString("Name"));
                map2.put("TicketID",json_data.getString("TicketID"));
                map2.put("Status", json_data.getString("Status"));
                System.out.println(map2);
                users.add(map2);
                System.out.println(users);

            System.out.println("********CHECKPOINT**********");

            System.out.println(map2);
            System.out.println(users);
            System.out.println("********CHECKPOINT  ENDS**********");





        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
    }
    return users;
}

void addHeader(){
    HashMap<String, String> map1;
    map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map1.put("Name", "Name");
    map1.put("TicketID", "TicketID");
    map1.put("Status", "Status");
    mylist_title.add(map1);

       try {
           adapter_title = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist_title, R.layout.row,
                   new String[] { "Name", "TicketID", "Status" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.Name,R.id.TicketID,R.id.Status});
           list_head.setAdapter(adapter_title);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Exception caught in addHeader");
          e.printStackTrace();
       }



}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "deprecation" })
public void addData() {


  try{
     adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, users, R.layout.row,
             new String[] { "Name", "TicketID", "Status" }, new int[] {
                     R.id.Name, R.id.TicketID, R.id.Status });
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

  }catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Exception in Add data method....");
      e.printStackTrace();

  }



    }

private void setupSearchView() {
    System.out.println(users);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Passengers here....");
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // tl.removeAllViewsInLayout();;
    flag=0;
    if (AppStatus.getInstance(this).isOnline()) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",8000).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Updating List", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        flag=1;
        Toast.makeText(this,"NO INTERNET CONNECTION DETECTED",8000).show();
        Log.v("Home", "############################You are not online!!!!");    
    }

    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
            android.R.color.holo_red_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light 
            );
    //final GetDataFromDB db = new GetDataFromDB();
    System.out.println("IN REFRESH METHOD");
    System.out.println(data);
    //data=null;
    //data = getdb.GetDataFromDB();
    //System.out.println("From onRefresh");
    //System.out.println(data);
    //System.out.println(users);



//  users = parseJSON(data2);


    //System.out.println(data2);
    //System.out.println(users);
    //addData(users); 
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(users);


            //  addData(users);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {



                    data = getdb.GetDataFromDB();

                    System.out.println(data);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            if(flag!=1){  //i.e  internet connnection available
                            users.clear();
                            users = parseJSON(data);
                            System.out.println(users);
                           // addHeader();
                             addData();
                             System.out.println(list);
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Retaining List",8000).show();
                                users = parseJSON(data);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
            }).start();



                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 2000);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
          System.out.println("IN IF CONDITION FIRST");
          System.out.println(users);
          list.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            System.out.println("IN else CONDITION FIRST");
              System.out.println(users);
            list.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
}
```

}
        [image: This is the base list....that is total items from the database. I want to implement search for searching items based on names]

[image: when i search for a particular name...it displays the row twice...I reckon this is happening because it filters the search based on 2 parameters from the Name as well as the TicketID field.......I want the app to display the search based on Name only]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp" />



<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#A3A3C2" />




<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#007A00"
        android:backgroundTint="#990000" />



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Use different array list object in parseJSON() method and return it.

Comment: can you please elaborate? Or is there any way of searching based only on the Name column and no other?